# Send a session variable from php to client side(HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am completely new to PHP and HTML. I want to send a session variable from PHP to client-side i,e HTML so that I can show which user is currently present.
If I just pass the variable to another php file present at the same location it does happen but I want to exchange the variable from server residing at local host to client at some other location Can any one help me in this 
Thanks

Comment: you should google this question. your question is too broad

Comment: Read This Whole Documentation And You will be better Understand PHP Session. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: echo `$_SESSION['ANY VAR'];`

Comment: I want to access the Session variable on the client side i,e HTML file .I see that accessing the session variable in PHP is very easy provided the PHP file is placed at the server side but Is there any way I can send it to client.

Comment: @rtfm I want to send the session variable back to the client side from server side my sever resides at local host and from there I want to send it to the html page so that whenever a user logs in it shows a welcome message with his username

Comment: @TarangP I want to send a variable named username so that when user logs in it sends a message with his username and I have already gone through the documentation thank you !

Answer (score 1):

let suppose you have a form in html

```
<form method="post" action="any.php">
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

now in php you are getting input value

```
<?php
if isset($_POST["name"]){
$_SESSION["sessionname"] = $_POST["name"];
}
?>
```

so far you have taken input value from html and have stored in session with the name **sessionname** now you are going to show it in html again

```
<h1>welcome user : <?php echo $_SESSION["sessionname"]; ?> </h1>
```

> you will need **session_start();** on the very beginning of all php pages otherwise you will lose the scope of session variable.

for more information here is link [wschools session](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: So it’s only possible if we pass values to php pages . Can we send the session variables to client side HTML pages

Comment: when you will write
<h1>welcome user : <?php echo $_SESSION["sessionname"]; ?> </h1>
it is already in html thats mean every one can see it (Your user too).

Comment: Does it even display when the html file is at a different place ?

Comment: write your code here. Make sure you are having session_start(); at the top of php pages otherwise you will lose the scope of session variable

Comment: where ever you want to display it write session variable there it should show.

Comment: My php file is in the local host and the html file is in another location . As u said I have mentioned the session _start() at the top of the php file but it shows nothing when placed in different server .Some times instead of opening the file it justs downloads the file .

Comment: i really don't know what you are trying to do. if you have both html and php in your hand so change your html extension to php like somepage.php and the top write session_start(); and where you want to show it write <?php echo $_SESSION["sessionname"]; ?> 
what do you mean by html is in another server?

Comment: My php is in the local host where I have the session variable from there I want to pass it to phone gapp server located at different IP. After doing what you have suggested the browser is downloading the PHP file instead of viewing it